# How to pass a parameter to exec(open().read())?

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, command-line-interface, exec

Writing a script which automates installing the Web Assembly git repo.  It downloads the repo, invokes commands to set it up.

I'm working off of this site's instructions: https://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/

**Target behavior:** 
`$ source ./emsdk_env.sh --build=Release`

This isn't so easy in Python as subprocess doesn't seem to cut it.  I've found the `exec(open("filename.sh").read())` command, but can't figure how to pass in the 
 
`--build=Release` parameter.

I think this is a key-value tuple and needs to be passed in as such, but how to do that hasn't been easy to find either.
This is the current code I'm attempting:

```
with open(emsdk_envFile) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), emsdk_envFile, 'exec')
    exec(code, 'Release')
```

This is the CLI output I get:

```
  File "installWebAssembly.py", line 184, in main
    code = compile(f.read(), emsdk_envFile, 'exec')
  File "/home/bcuser/Git/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh", line 19
    if [ "$SRC" = "" ]; then
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's been suggested to use subprocess.  However, when I run a verbose command in Subprocess.call(), I get this output:

```
subprocess.call('source /home/bcuser/Git/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh --build=Release', shell=True)
...
$ python myScript.py
OUTPUT:
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

The end goal is to automate all steps required to install and use Web Assembly. The purpose of the *emsdk_env.sh* file is to add relevant environment variables and directory entries to PATH to set up the current terminal for easy access to the compiler tools.

Comment: `exec` is for executing Python code, not shell scripts—for them you should use `subprocess`. You can pass command-line arguments using it.

Comment: oh.  I read that subprocess was not for executing things that needed to make changes to the parent shell.  Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Hmm, using `subprocess.call('source /home/bcuser/Git/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh --build=Release', shell=True)` doesn't seem to help.  I get a response of: `/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found`

Comment: Yes, I believe that's generally true (about updating the parent shell) . You may need to create your own script that invokes the emsdk script and then does whatever else you want done. You should also add the appropriate OS tag to your question.

Comment: It's also not entire clear what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish. Please [edit] your question and clarify what the expected results are.